# Missing frames when drawing in CVDisplayLink Callback

Tags: macos, opengl

In a OS X for scientific research, we render graphics using NSOpenGLView on a second LCD display.  That works fine if we put our drawing code in drawRect: and drive it with a timer.  However we need to better synchronize with the frame rate, so we are attempting migration to CVDisplayLink, as described in [Apple Q&A 1385](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1385/_index.html).

We have used the code from Listing 1 of that sample, except instead of calling CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays(), we call CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay() and pass in the ID of our second LCD display.

We have moved our drawing code from -drawRect: to a new -draw method which is called by our CVDisplayLink callback as you can see in the code below.

I notice that OS X is creating not one but *two* threads named *CVDisplayLink*.  They call our callback alternately.  Is that normal?

Randomly, on maybe about 10% of the frames, the scene created by our drawing code appears on the second LCD display as desired.  For the other 90% of the frames, this display shows garbage, or solid white, even though I think we are clearing the display in our callback.

Oh, I inherited this project, and am new to OpenGL, so it may be something really simple, or completely unrelated to my description.  I would appreciate any clues.

```
- (void)prepareOpenGL
{
    GLint swapInt = 1;
    stimGLContext = [self openGLContext];
    [stimGLContext setValues:&swapInt forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];

    // Create a display link capable
    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(self.displayID, &displayLink);

    // Set the renderer output callback function
    CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(
                                   displayLink,
                                   &MyDisplayLinkCallback,
                                   (__bridge void *)(self));

    // Set the display link for the current renderer
    CGLContextObj cglContext = [[self openGLContext] CGLContextObj];
    CGLPixelFormatObj cglPixelFormat = [[self pixelFormat] CGLPixelFormatObj];
    CVDisplayLinkSetCurrentCGDisplayFromOpenGLContext(
                                                      displayLink,
                                                      cglContext,
                                                      cglPixelFormat);

    // Activate the display link
    CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink);
}

// Renderer output callback function
static CVReturn MyDisplayLinkCallback(
                                      CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
                                      const CVTimeStamp* now,
                                      const CVTimeStamp* outputTime,
                                      CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
                                      CVOptionFlags* flagsOut,
                                      void* displayLinkContext)
{
    CVReturn result = [(__bridge StimulusGLView*)displayLinkContext getFrameForTime:outputTime];
    return result;
}

- (CVReturn)getFrameForTime:(const CVTimeStamp*)outputTime
{
    /* We are on a secondary "CVDisplayLink" thread here. */

    NSOpenGLContext* context = [self openGLContext];
    [context makeCurrentContext];
    CGLLockContext([context CGLContextObj]);

    [self draw] ;

    CGLFlushDrawable([context CGLContextObj]);
    CGLUnlockContext([context CGLContextObj]);

    return kCVReturnSuccess;
}

- (void)draw
{
    //  Clear out and show a solid blue background
    glClearColor((GLclampf)0, (GLclampf), (GLclampf).8, 0);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    ... more glXxxxx() drawing statements follow here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the call to `CVDisplayLinkSetCurrentCGDisplayFromOpenGLContext()`: the docs say that it "chooses the display with the lowest refresh rate." I think this call is setting the display link's `CGDisplay` again, maybe to a different display from `self.displayID` and causing your problems.

If that doesn't work, you could try using `CVDisplayLinkCreateWithActiveCGDisplays()`, and then call `CVDisplayLinkSetCurrentCGDisplay()` to set it to your secondary display.

Comment: Thank you, Brendan.  I tried both of your suggestions, and also a couple slight variations that came to my mind, but still get the same result.  Do you know is it normal to have two *CVDisplayLink* threads running alternately?

Comment: I just tested my (fairly simple) OpenGL app that uses a `CVDisplayLink`, and the callback is only getting called from one thread.

Comment: Thank you for that clue, Brendan.  I've set this aside for now, but will be back when I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I should have posted more code.

Among the code I omitted in -draw was a call to -[NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer].  This was inherited from our old code which does not use CVDisplayLink.  When I pasted Apple's CVDisplayLink Sample code into our project, I didn't realize that CGLFlushDrawable() in their code was equivalent to its Objective-C wrapper, -[NSOpenGLContext flushBuffer] which we were already doing in -draw.

Interestingly, I found when experimenting that, it looks good if the buffer is flushed an odd number of times per frame (1 or 3) but flickers if, as I was doing, the buffer is flushed an even number of times (2).  I think that makes sense because this context is double buffered.